# Converting some Pre-Tax 401k Contributions to Roth Contributions

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-401k, roth-conversion

Is it possible to convert some Pre-Tax 401k contributions to Roth contributions each year? Since I would have to pay taxes on the amount converted I wouldn't be able to do it all at one time.

Comment: I assume your employer does not offer a Roth 401(k)? What's the rationale for converting every year? Could you just put the tax you'd spend in a Roth instead?

Comment: @DStanley I believe the individual contribution limit for 2023 is 22,500.  Would the amount you convert from Pre-Tax to Roth go against the 22,500 you're allowed to contribute?

Comment: No - conversions are not considered contributions. And that limit is for a Roth 401(k); Roth IRAs have a contribution limit of 6,000 to 7,000 depending on age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - provided that your employer allows in-service withdrawals/conversions, of course.

There is no limit to the number of 401(k) to Roth conversions you can do in a year.